# Transfer variables between functions

Tags: angular, typescript

I have little problem with sharing variable between functions. In my case I first call function watchLocation() which is for updating location variables and I need everytime when I call to setLocation() transfer location variables to this function but variables is still empty. Maybe I am doing something wrong but it makes sense for me.

My code is here:

```
export class LocationComponent {

@ViewChild("mapbox") _mapbox: ElementRef;

  player_latitude:string;
  player_longitude:string;

  constructor() {
    this.player_latitude;
    this.player_longitude;
  }

watchLocation() { 
      let watchId = watchLocation(
      function (loc) {
          if (loc) {
              this.player_latitude = loc.latitude;
              this.player_longitude = loc.longitude;
          }
      }, 
      function(e){
          console.log("Error: " + e.message);
      }, 
      {desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, minimumUpdateTime : 1000 * 20});
}

setLocation() {
    alert(this.player_latitude);
    this._mapbox.nativeElement.setCenter({
                      lat: this.player_latitude,
                      lng: this.player_longitude,
                      animated: true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use anonymous functions. Use arrow functions. This question is being asked again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `()=>{}` instead of `function () {}` then `this.` will work

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions